# Low Yearly Archives Showing Total News Articles in Two Languages

Tags: transcribe, low, low-yearly-archives

I have a bilingual website where I am using Low Yearly Archives to create a dropdown that shows how many news articles have been added in a single year using the {entries_in_year} tag. Only issue is it is showing double what the entries are because I have a bilingual site (using Transcribe) so each entry has an associated entry in another laguage. Is there a way for the {entries_in_year} tag to only show the count for the number of entries in that year for that specific language?

Thanks.
Stephen.

Answer (score 1):

Low Yearly Archives isn't specifically compatible with Transcribe. But if the languages can be differentiated by, for example, status, then you can use that parameter to filter the entries.

Otherwise, some sort of hack would be required.